# Is there a way to find out the gateway of a mobile network connection?

Tags: java, android, networking, gateway

Hi I want to read details on mobile network connection, like ip adress, dns servers etc. and the GATEWAY which the network normally uses to send data to the internet. Since this is a TCP/IP connection there has to be one. So I tried to find solutions or examples to find out the Gateway of a mobile network connection (Not Wifi!!!!).

Under API Level 21 there exists LinkProperties, but my Library will not be used by tablets and smartphones having this min SDK.

So under LOLLIPOP I do have this solution

```
if (Utils.hasLollipop()) {
                LinkProperties linkProperties = connectivityManager.getLinkProperties(mobileNetwork);

                if (linkProperties != null) {
                    List<InetAddress> dnsServers = linkProperties.getDnsServers();

                    for (InetAddress dns : dnsServers) {
                        if (!status.getmDNS().contains(dns.getHostAddress())) {
                            status.getmDNS().add(dns.getHostAddress());
                        }
                    }

                    List<RouteInfo> routeInfos = linkProperties.getRoutes();

                    if (routeInfos != null && routeInfos.size() > 0) {
                        for (RouteInfo i : routeInfos) {
                            if (i.getGateway() != null) {
                                status.setmGateway(i.getGateway().getHostAddress());
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
              ... Solution for devices API Level < 21
            }
```

Do anybody has an Idea what i can do?!

Thanks ;D

**EDIT:**

According to the comments of the answer from "Lance Preston", I did write an example code. If there is any other way, or if you have any bugfixes just let us know.

```
private static final String ipv4Pattern = "\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}";
private static final String interfacePattern = "\\s*dev\\s*";
private static final String defaultGatewayPattern = "default\\s*via\\s*";
private static final String noCapturingPattern = "(?:%s)";

public static List<String> getGateways(String interfaceName) {
    try {
        List<String> gateways = new ArrayList<>();
        Pattern defaultpattern = Pattern.compile(String.format(noCapturingPattern, defaultGatewayPattern) + "(" + ipv4Pattern + ")" + String.format(noCapturingPattern, (interfacePattern + interfaceName)));
        Pattern ipAddressPattern = Pattern.compile(String.format(noCapturingPattern, ipv4Pattern + "\\s*via\\s*") + "(" + ipv4Pattern + ")" + String.format(noCapturingPattern, (interfacePattern + interfaceName)));
        Process result = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ip route show");
        BufferedReader output = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(result.getInputStream()));
        String line = output.readLine();

        while (line != null) {
            if (!line.isEmpty()) {
                Matcher defaultMatcher = defaultpattern.matcher(line);
                if (defaultMatcher.find() && defaultMatcher.groupCount() == 1) {
                    String gatewayAddress = defaultMatcher.group(1);
                    if (gatewayAddress != null && !gatewayAddress.isEmpty() && !gateways.contains(gatewayAddress)) {
                        gateways.add(gatewayAddress);
                    }
                }

                Matcher ipAddressMatcher = ipAddressPattern.matcher(line);
                if (ipAddressMatcher.find() && ipAddressMatcher.groupCount() == 1) {
                    String gatewayAddress = ipAddressMatcher.group(1);
                    if (gatewayAddress != null && !gatewayAddress.isEmpty() && !gateways.contains(gatewayAddress)) {
                        gateways.add(gatewayAddress);
                    }
                }
            }
            line = output.readLine();
        }

        return gateways;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This linux command can lend some *Gateway* info - `netstat -r -n` or `ip route show`
You can then parse the output of `ip route show` along the lines of `default via xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`

This will help you out.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView tv;
EditText et;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.out);
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt);

    String [] res = executeInShell("ip route show").split("\n");
    String gatewayInfo [] = res[0].split(" ");

    et.setText("ip route show");
    et.setSelection(et.getText().length());

    tv.setText(gatewayInfo[2].toString());

    Log.d("Response", executeInShell("ip route show"));


}

public static String executeInShell(String command) {

        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

        Process p;
        try {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            p.waitFor();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
                output.append(line + "\n");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String response = output.toString();
        return response;

   }

}
```

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_gravity="center"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:text="Get My Gateway" />
<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txt" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/out"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

*Response from LogCat*

[image: Response from LogCat]

*Screenshot from device*

[image: Screenshot from device]

Comment: I already tried this....

    Process result = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("netstat -rn");BufferedReader output = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(result.getInputStream()));
            String line = output.readLine();

Comment: What is the result ?

Comment: A routing table looking like:

tcp  0  0 10.133.238.143:39569   40.115.1.44:443        TIME_WAIT
tcp6 0  0 ::ffff:192.168.149.156:40245 ::ffff:74.125.206.16:993 ESTABLISHED
...

which tells me which outgoing port is routed to which ip adress from the network interface :

Under API level 21 I get as Gateway at line:

i.getGateway().getHostAdress() : 10.133.238.1 

which is never mentioned in the list netstat -rn
...

Comment: I'll give it a try ;-)

Comment: Process result = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ip route show");
returns the broadcast address only:

10.133.238.0/24 dev rmnet0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.133.238.143

Comment: Updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: Activated WLan:

default via 192.168.149.254 dev wlan0  metric 309 
192.168.149.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.149.156  metric 309 

Activated Mobile Network:

10.133.238.0/24 dev rmnet0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.133.238.143 

There is no default gateway...

Comment: That's your connection's problem. The solution works.

Comment: I think it's not the connection problem, rather than a hardware problem:

Your code works on ASus K014, but not on the Samsung SM-T815

Comment: And have you looked at the Gateway Address it's strange that every gateway address is just 1 bit higher in the host section. I cannot believe that this should be the right Address. Do you have any explanation for this ?